# Как открыть новую вкладку в Хроме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Нужно в связке Питон+Селениум открыть новую вкладку в Хроме, но гуглил, и инфы не нашёл.

Алгоритм функции `works()`:

1. Если `i==n`, программа прекращает свою роботу.
2. Если `j==50`, программа открывает новое окно с нужным сайтом.
3. Если эти варианты не срабатывают, программа открывает новую вкладку в последнем открытом экземпляре окна браузера с нужным сайтом.

Код:

```
#-*-coding:UTF-8-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import time
import subprocess
import sys
import os

i=0

def works(url, n):
    global i
    if i==n:
        os.startfile(r'5.py')
        sys.exit()
    elif j==50:
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\selenium\chromedriver.exe",
                                  chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        print (n)
        print (i) # проверка на правильное выполнение цикла
        try:
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.find_element_by_id('videoContainer')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Такой элемент на сайте не существует!')
            subprocess.getoutput("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")
            subprocess.getoutput("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe")
            i = 0
            j = 0
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            print('Такой элемент на сайте существует!')
            time.sleep(3)
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
            print (i) # проверка на правильное выполнение цикла
        finally:
            f = open('i.txt', 'w')
            s = str(i)
            f.write(s)
            f.close()
            f = open('monitor.txt', 'w')
            f.close()
            works(url, n)
    else:


def main():
    f = open('monitor.txt', 'w')
    f.close()
    url = input("Введи ссылку на трансляцию: ")
    n = int(input("Введи количество просмотров трансляции: "))
    f = open('url.txt', 'w')
    f.write(url)
    f.close()
    f = open('n.txt', 'w')
    s = str(n)
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
    works(url, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558909/2787185

Два: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432939/2787185

Основная идея:

```
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

s = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=s
    )
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://python-forum.io/Thread-Need-Help-Opening-A-New-Tab-in-Selenium')
# Open a new window
# This does not change focus to the new window for the driver.
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(3)
# Switch to the new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
time.sleep(3)
# close the active tab
driver.close()
time.sleep(3)
# Switch back to the first tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.get("http://google.se")
time.sleep(3)
# Close the only tab, will also close the browser.
driver.close()
```